# Array of textviews not populating properly from an array

Tags: android, arrays, textview

I'm trying to create an `Array` of `TextViews` that each get populated from an `Array` of objects, but each `TextView` ends up displaying the last object that I enter.

I've initiated the array of TextViews with

```
    TextView[] loanViewDisplay = new TextView[5];
```

and inside of my onCreate, I have

```
    loanViewDisplay[0] = findViewById(R.id.loanView1);
    loanViewDisplay[1] = findViewById(R.id.loanView2);
    loanViewDisplay[2] = findViewById(R.id.loanView3);
    loanViewDisplay[3] = findViewById(R.id.loanView4);
    loanViewDisplay[4] = findViewById(R.id.loanView5);
```

I have an addNewLoan button that initiates an Intent and startActivityForResult. The new loan gets added to a array called arrayOfLoans and the program returns to this activity where I want to list each loan from arrayOfLoans in its own TextView.

```
    for(int i=0; i<listOfLoans.length; i++){
        if(arrayOfLoans[i] != null){
            loanViewDisplay[i].setText(arrayOfLoans[i].loanInformation());
        }
    }
```

If I add one loan with a principle of $5000, the output is perfect with

```
    Loan 1: Principle $5000
```

but if I then click my addNewLoan button and add a second loan with a value of $2000, my output turns into

```
    Loan 2: Principle $2000
    Loan 2: Principle $2000
```

I know my data is being added to arrayOfLoans properly. I've narrowed the problem down to the array of TextViews. Thanks for the help

Comment: How you fill `arrayOfLoans`? Or can you log the `arrayOfLoans`? maybe all strings in the array are same.

Comment: So I originally thought this wasn't my problem, but I've determined that when I add a new loan, all the loans in are being replaced somehow. I switched to an ArrayList and declared my ArrayList in main activity with public static ArrayList<Loan> listOfLoans = new ArrayList<Loan>(); and in a different class I create a loan with Loan loan = new Loan(principle, rate); and add it to the ArrayList with listOfLoans.add(loan); When I try to access the loans in a loop, every index of listOfLoans returns the same information. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your loop you don't need loop for display name in text view . What you need is just number at which your last position array was populated .

For that, set `i=0` initially then use below code line .

```
if(arrayOfLoans[i] != null){
        loanViewDisplay[i].setText(arrayOfLoans[i].loanInformation());
        i++;
}
```

Comment: When I try that, it just changes the first TextView to whatever the last element in the array is populated with. I know it has to be something with how the TextView array is declared because even if I don't use a loop at all to try to assign text to the textview, I have the same problem I described in my post. If I do 
loanViewDisplay[0].setText(arrayOfLoans[0].loanInformation());
loanViewDisplay[1].setText(arrayOfLoans[1].loanInformation());
I only get the second loan displayed in both TextViews.

Comment: Use array list then.
            ArrayList<TextView> asd = new ArrayList<>();
            asd.add(tv1);
            asd.add(tv2);
            asd.add(tv3);
            asd.add(tv4);
            asd.add(tv5);